# AttributeError: GameObject instance has no attribute - PyGame

Tags: python, pygame

```
class GameObject:
def __init__(self, x=0, y=0, width=0, high=0, imName="", imAlpha=False ):
    self.x = x # on screen
    self.y = y
    self.width = width
    self.high = high
    self.imageName = imName
    self.imageAlpha = imAlpha
    self.image

def loadImage(self):
    self.image = pygame.image.load(self.imageName)
    self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (self.width, self.high))
    if self.imageAlpha == True:
        self.image = self.image.convert_alpha() 
    else:
        self.image = self.image.convert()


pygame.init()
player = GameObject(px0, py0, width, high, "player.png", True)
player.loadImage()
```

Any ideas why I have the following error?

> AttributeError: GameObject instance has no attribute 'image'

Comment: what's the point of `self.image` alone in `__init__` ?, maybe use  `self.image = None` instead if you want to declare it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's bad practice not to do so, but you don't need to declare object attributes in the constructor (**init**). When you wrote self.image, it tried accessing an attribute that didn't exist yet.
I'd advise on doing self.image = None until you load it, but removing that line entirely would work as well.

Comment: You are write! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

In the last line of `__init__`, which is called when you define `player`, you are attempting to access `self.image`, which does not exist.